# Twitter Fabric xcode - Error uploading distribution: Archive Distribution Error: -3

Tags: twitter-fabric

I am trying to distribute a new beta version using fabric plugin for mac.
Network and proxy are correctly configured, I can access a url that requires proxy athentication, using a browser.

When I try to upload the app, the process finishes with error -3 (http error 400):

Archive distribution error: -3
Could not upload the distribution. The operation couldn't be completed. (HTTP error 400.)

Screenshot: http://i62.tinypic.com/mjl81t.jpg

Tried without success:

- Restart xcode, fabric plugin
- Quit fabric.app, clear caché (rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac), open fabric.app

Could you please help me, to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Eduard.

Comment: The screenshot is missing!

Comment: SOLVED: I reviewed the app generated and it's ok. It seems a connectivity problem. I have changed the network cable connection, and I have distributed the application successfully!

Comment: You also can share your build via CLI https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html

Comment: One of the common trouble - name of project. I have some problems with project names containing spaces. Archive, project, target named with spaces generates errors -9 and -3.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when **I changed the bundle identifier** of my target and tried to distribute it as the same app as before.

I solved this issue by registering my application as a new app in Fabric.