# Fabric - Crashlytics IOS archive upload issue (Error 3 http 400)

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have an error -3 http 400 (the 18 of August 2016) when I try to upload my iOS app on Fabric. 
*To fix this issue, I tried to :*

- Check StackOverflow : [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887646/crashlytics-archive-distribution-error-3), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245428/twitter-fabric-xcode-error-uploading-distribution-archive-distribution-error),
- clean the build folder,
- restart the Fabric desktop app (on mac),
- update the framework SDKs,
  ==> got no luck.

Then I check the Fabric status : http://status.fabric.io/history , everything seems ok.
Then I tried with a dummy app that contains a pod, **it worked !**
So I tried to change the cable, change the internet connection, didn't work either.
Then I tried to downsize the app (about 60Mb) to 20 Mo, no luck here too. The connection seems to be cut at approximatively 5 Mb every time.

*The only strange things I have seen are :*

- the archive list in Fabric for my app are periodically disappearing. To fix this, I need to build a new archive, The archive list will reappear.
- Fabric seems to think that my SDK are always outdated and ask me to update to SDK 3.7.3 even if I do the update. I can see the update worked as I have some modified frameworks files in my git repository.

If someone can helps, it would be nice,
thanks.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - seems like there are a couple of funky things going on. If you upload the .IPA manually, does that work? Try using: 

/path/to/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> \
-ipaPath /path/to/my.ipa -emails TestEmail@fabric.io,AmazingTester@twitter.com \
-notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt \
-groupAliases GroupAlias,GroupAlias2 \
-notifications YES reference: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html

Comment: Hello mike, thanks for the answer. To be precise I have retried this morning with the Fabric app, and it is still not working (error 3 http error 400). But if I test with the command line you gave me, it works (I have converted the archive into an ipa).

Comment: Thanks, if you'd like, please send over your logs at this location: ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.crashlytics.mac/v3/active to support(at)fabric(dot)io for me and the team to look into.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem...

I solve this!

The problem was the access rights to the app, the manager invited me to the app, and works... Good luck!